# Ir a otro formulario al confirmar en Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Estoy usando Sweetalert para mandar una alerta a la hora de querer cancelar la modificación de un usuario.

Pero lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario de click en "Confirmar", en la alerta de Sweetalert, lo mande a otro formulario.

Encontré una solución en la que usa Ajax, pero no se si lo estoy haciendo correctamente.

La alerta la tengo en "modificar_user.php" y quiero que al confirmar que quiere que cancele la modificación lo envie a "listaDeUsuarios.php".

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   
   function cancelarModificacion(){
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Esta seguro de cancelar la modificación',
        text: "No se guardaran los datos modificados",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar"
        
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

         $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
    url: 'location:listaDeUsuarios.php',
   });

        }
      })
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: por que no simplemente agregas ```window.location="listaDeUsuarios.php";``` dentro del if

Comment: Si funciono!! Yo ya habia usado el windows.location pero no me habia funcionado, creo que lo habia puesto mal. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Como lo mencionan en el comentario en vez de utilizar ajax seria mejor solo utilizar window.location.href.

```js
 
   function cancelarModificacion(){
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Esta seguro de cancelar la modificación',
        text: "No se guardaran los datos modificados",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar"
        
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          window.location.href = "listaDeUsuarios.php";
        }
      })
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="cancelarModificacion()">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Si lo implemente y funciono, gracias.